# Is there a master UI element that controls all subviews?

Tags: iphone

If you have a seperate UIViewcontroller for each screen, along with its own NIB file, what is the master UI control that is controlling which viewcontroller to fire up and when?

Is this the job of the Controller and there is no master UI object that manages this?

I am very new, so maybe I need to understand things from the ground up, any links would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are some kind of view controllers like UINavigationController or UITabBarController that made just that.

UITabBarController controls a buch of viewcontroller that you provide when instanciating it.

UINavigationController is the one that create a toolbar at the top with the back button when it makes sens.